# LogicApp - Changing JSON

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I have some JSON like this produced from a step in the LogicApp I am working on.

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "displayName": "John Doe",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "gender": "Male",
    "jobTitle": "Customer Service Representative",
    "workPhone": "555-555-5555",
    "workPhoneExtension": null,
    "skypeUsername": "JohnDoe",
    "facebook": "JohnDoeFacebook"
  },
  {
    "id": 124,
    "displayName": "James Deen",
    "firstName": "James",
    "lastName": "Deen",
    "gender": "Male",
    "jobTitle": "Job Title",
    "workPhone": "555-555-5555",
    "workPhoneExtension": null,
    "skypeUsername": "JamesDean",
    "facebook": "JamesDeenFacebook"
  }
]
```

I was hoping the use of the SELECT component would allow me to exclude fields and essentially rename fields.

How would I transform the above JSON into the following?

```
[
  {
    "An Id": 123,
    "Full Name": "John Doe",
    "New Field Added", "A value which is new"
  },
  {
    "An Id": 124,
    "Full Name": "James Deen",
    "New Field Added", "A new value"
  }
]
```

At the moment, I am getting issues with FOREACH components being added. I have also used FOREACH loops and various ways to achieve this change.

Would very much appreciate someone explaining the best way to do this.

For example with a SELECT added with one field mapped I see
[image]

When adding another it adds a foreach changes things.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is because I was choosing the incorrect from value. In the list of fields I had each field from the JSON, plus the array name holding the values, plus the a 'body' item.

It goes wrong when you select the array name , in this case `employees` but if you use the `body` item, it works properly.

[image]